# C++ only allowing one input

Tags: c++

When I run this code I enter one name and then it prints the rest of the `cout` statements. It does not allow me to enter anything else other than one input when I have multiple inputs. How can this error be fixed?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct info {
    char Firstname;
    char Lastname;
};

int main()
{
    int month;
    int date;
    info person1, person2, person3, person4, person5;
    cout << "Enter the First Name of 1 friend." << endl;
    cin >> person1.Firstname;
    cout << "Now enter their last name." << endl;
    cin >> person1.Lastname;
    cout << "Enter the number of the month the person was born in: " << endl;
    cin >> month;
    cout << "Now Enter your birth date:" << endl;
    cin >> date;
    if ((month == 1 && date >= 20) || (month == 2 && date <= 18))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is AQUARIUS\n";

    }
    else if ((month == 2 && date >= 19) || (month == 3 && date <= 20))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is PISCES\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 3 && date >= 21) || (month == 4 && date <= 19))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is ARIES\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 4 && date >= 20) || (month == 5 && date <= 20))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is TAURUS\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 5 && date >= 21) || (month == 6 && date <= 20))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is GEMINI\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 6 && date >= 21) || (month == 7 && date <= 22))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is CANCER\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 7 && date <= 23) || (month == 8 && date <= 22))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is LEO\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 8 && date >= 23) || (month == 9 && date <= 22))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is VIRGO\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 9 && date >= 23) || (month == 10 && date <= 22))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is LIBRA\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 10 && date >= 23) || (month == 11 && date <= 21))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is SCORPIO\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 11 && date >= 22) || (month == 12 && date <= 21))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is SAGUITTARIUS\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 12 && date >= 22) || (month == 1 && date <= 19))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is CAPRICORN\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " INVALID INPUT";
    }

    cout << "Enter the First Name of 1 friend." << endl;
    cin >> person2.Firstname;
    cout << "Now enter their last name." << endl;
    cin >> person2.Lastname;
    cout << "Enter the number of the month the person was born in: " << endl;
    cin >> month;
    cout << "Now Enter your birth date:" << endl;
    cin >> date;
    if ((month == 1 && date >= 20) || (month == 2 && date <= 18))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is AQUARIUS\n";

    }
    else if ((month == 2 && date >= 19) || (month == 3 && date <= 20))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is PISCES\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 3 && date >= 21) || (month == 4 && date <= 19))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is ARIES\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 4 && date >= 20) || (month == 5 && date <= 20))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is TAURUS\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 5 && date >= 21) || (month == 6 && date <= 20))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is GEMINI\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 6 && date >= 21) || (month == 7 && date <= 22))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is CANCER\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 7 && date <= 23) || (month == 8 && date <= 22))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is LEO\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 8 && date >= 23) || (month == 9 && date <= 22))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is VIRGO\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 9 && date >= 23) || (month == 10 && date <= 22))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is LIBRA\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 10 && date >= 23) || (month == 11 && date <= 21))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is SCORPIO\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 11 && date >= 22) || (month == 12 && date <= 21))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is SAGUITTARIUS\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 12 && date >= 22) || (month == 1 && date <= 19))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is CAPRICORN\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " INVALID INPUT";
    }

    cout << "Enter the First Name of 1 friend." << endl;
    cin >> person3.Firstname;
    cout << "Now enter their last name." << endl;
    cin >> person3.Lastname;
    cout << "Enter the number of the month the person was born in: " << endl;
    cin >> month;
    cout << "Now Enter your birth date:" << endl;
    cin >> date;

    if ((month == 1 && date >= 20) || (month == 2 && date <= 18))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is AQUARIUS\n";

    }
    else if ((month == 2 && date >= 19) || (month == 3 && date <= 20))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is PISCES\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 3 && date >= 21) || (month == 4 && date <= 19))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is ARIES\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 4 && date >= 20) || (month == 5 && date <= 20))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is TAURUS\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 5 && date >= 21) || (month == 6 && date <= 20))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is GEMINI\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 6 && date >= 21) || (month == 7 && date <= 22))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is CANCER\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 7 && date <= 23) || (month == 8 && date <= 22))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is LEO\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 8 && date >= 23) || (month == 9 && date <= 22))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is VIRGO\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 9 && date >= 23) || (month == 10 && date <= 22))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is LIBRA\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 10 && date >= 23) || (month == 11 && date <= 21))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is SCORPIO\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 11 && date >= 22) || (month == 12 && date <= 21))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is SAGUITTARIUS\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 12 && date >= 22) || (month == 1 && date <= 19))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is CAPRICORN\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " INVALID INPUT";
    }
    cout << "Enter the First Name of 1 friend." << endl;
    cin >> person4.Firstname;
    cout << "Now enter their last name." << endl;
    cin >> person4.Lastname;
    cout << "Enter the number of the month the person was born in: " << endl;
    cin >> month;
    cout << "Now Enter your birth date:" << endl;
    cin >> date;
    if ((month == 1 && date >= 20) || (month == 2 && date <= 18))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is AQUARIUS\n";

    }
    else if ((month == 2 && date >= 19) || (month == 3 && date <= 20))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is PISCES\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 3 && date >= 21) || (month == 4 && date <= 19))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is ARIES\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 4 && date >= 20) || (month == 5 && date <= 20))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is TAURUS\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 5 && date >= 21) || (month == 6 && date <= 20))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is GEMINI\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 6 && date >= 21) || (month == 7 && date <= 22))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is CANCER\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 7 && date <= 23) || (month == 8 && date <= 22))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is LEO\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 8 && date >= 23) || (month == 9 && date <= 22))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is VIRGO\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 9 && date >= 23) || (month == 10 && date <= 22))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is LIBRA\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 10 && date >= 23) || (month == 11 && date <= 21))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is SCORPIO\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 11 && date >= 22) || (month == 12 && date <= 21))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is SAGUITTARIUS\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 12 && date >= 22) || (month == 1 && date <= 19))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is CAPRICORN\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " INVALID INPUT";
    }

    cout << "Enter the First Name of 1 friend." << endl;
    cin >> person5.Firstname;
    cout << "Now enter their last name." << endl;
    cin >> person5.Lastname;
    cout << "Enter the number of the month the person was born in: " << endl;
    cin >> month;
    cout << "Now Enter your birth date:" << endl;
    cin >> date;
    if ((month == 1 && date >= 20) || (month == 2 && date <= 18))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is AQUARIUS\n";

    }
    else if ((month == 2 && date >= 19) || (month == 3 && date <= 20))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is PISCES\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 3 && date >= 21) || (month == 4 && date <= 19))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is ARIES\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 4 && date >= 20) || (month == 5 && date <= 20))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is TAURUS\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 5 && date >= 21) || (month == 6 && date <= 20))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is GEMINI\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 6 && date >= 21) || (month == 7 && date <= 22))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is CANCER\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 7 && date <= 23) || (month == 8 && date <= 22))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is LEO\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 8 && date >= 23) || (month == 9 && date <= 22))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is VIRGO\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 9 && date >= 23) || (month == 10 && date <= 22))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is LIBRA\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 10 && date >= 23) || (month == 11 && date <= 21))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is SCORPIO\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 11 && date >= 22) || (month == 12 && date <= 21))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is SAGUITTARIUS\n";
    }
    else if ((month == 12 && date >= 22) || (month == 1 && date <= 19))
    {
        cout << " Your zodiac sign is CAPRICORN\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " INVALID INPUT";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A variable of type `char` can store exactly one character. It seems unlikely that all your friends have such short names. Read about `std::string` in your favorite C++ textbook.

Comment: Ever heard of this thing called an array?  Or a loop?  Having five copies of your whole program just makes fixing bugs five times as hard.

Comment: @user3138302 You repeated the exact code multiple times in your program.  What if you had 100 friends?  Write the same code 100 times over?

Answer (score 0):

As @Igor Tandetnik has pointed out you are using a char in your structure.
So if you have entered a name with 3 or more characters then it will just bypass the next `cin` function call.

Change your structure to use an array of char and use `getline` function of `cin`.

```
struct info {
    char Firstname[50];
    char Lastname[50];
};
```

Then in your main function:

```
cout << "Enter the First Name of 1 friend." << endl;
cin.getline(person1.Firstname,sizeof(person1.Firstname));
cout << "Now enter their last name." << endl;
cin.getline(person1.Lastname,sizeof(person1.Lastname));
```